# Как создавать txt файл на рабочем столе в windwos 10 с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

столкнулся с проблемой что создавая txt файл в любой директории он создается, а в дириктории C:\Users\epicb\Desktop он не создается и выдает ошибку syntax erorr хотя я только изменил директорию, и есть еще один вопрос, если я скину кому-то эту программу то это не сработает из за того что разные имена пользователей, как можно заменить epicb на имя юзера который запустил программу.

вот часть кода`file = open("C:\Users\epicb\Desktop/Hello_world !", "w", encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# импортируем модуль, который поможет получить имя пользователя
import getpass

# получаем имя пользователя и присваиваем его в переменную USER_NAME
# так как у всех разное имя пользователя
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()

# присваиваем путь с USER_NAME и имя файла в переменную path
path = r'C:\Users\%s\Desktop\Hello_world.txt' % USER_NAME

file = open(path, 'w')  # создаем txt файл
file.write('Hello, World!') # записываем текст
file.close()  # закрываем файл
```

Comment: Поясните, что именно сделано и почему. А то польза ответа сводится к минимуму.

Comment: изменил ответ, вроде все объяснил

Answer (score 1):

Лично я в таких случаях юзаю модуль os, и вам советую.
Сначала нужно через данный модуль узнать имя пользователя.

```
import os
user = os.getenv("USERPROFILE") # выведет C:\\Users\\юзер, через ос можно вывести чистое имя пользователя, но так будет удобнее
```

Затем уже нужно создать сам файл.

```
import os
user = os.getenv("USERPROFILE")
filename = user + "\\Desktop\\file.txt"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
f.close()
```

Надеюсь помог.